# Scrape URLs in a search result with Python through a "load more" button (Bulgarian site)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape the entire result set of a search like this:
(this search is for "potatoes")

картофи | Vesti.bg
https://www.vesti.bg/tarsene?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8

The thing is there is a "load more" button right here ("ВИЖ ОЩЕ" / "see more"):

**selector**:

body > div.container-fluid > div.vesti-mainWrap > div > section > div.main-content.leading-news.search-page-form > div > div > div.col-12.section-more-holder

**xpath:**

/html/body/div[1](https://www.vesti.bg/tarsene?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8)/div[2]/div/section/div[1](https://www.vesti.bg/tarsene?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8)/div/div/div[32]

and I can't figure how to play with requests and post/get methods in order to load the entire result set (which I'll scrape after that).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way of accomplishing that would be to use the library [selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/).
You can simply do `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div1/div[2]/div/section/div1/div/div/div[32]').click()` to atomatically click on the button. Afterwards you would scrape the freshly loaded data.

Comment: Somehow I can't find my way through the installation, because I don't want to use Chrome. Other answer would be appreciated more.

Comment: You are not required to use a Chrome driver: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/#drivers

Comment: well, I have tried with Edge and Opera simulation, and it didn't work. So again, I'd appreciate another solution.

Comment: or I might just try using it again.

Comment: can't really make it work. :/ I start a browser successfully, load the page and selenium won't find anything given by xpath or class name. :/